# Selenium - Enable elementusing javascript is not working in Jenkins

Tags: javascript, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

The test is to upload a file but the problem is that the element is hidden. I used a javascript to make the element visible (refer to the code below). The code work perfectly when I execute it in my local machine. But when I integrate the script in the jenkins pipeline and it is now executed using chrome in selenium grid, it resulted to an error. "not absolute path".
Note: this is not the issue of the location of the file because we are sending a string. That error is pointing to the element.

```
// Hidden Upload File TextBox
public static void uploadFileDropZoneJS(String file) {
    WebElement elem = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
    String js = "$(\"input[type='file']\").appendTo('.bulk-uploader');$(\"input[type='file']\").removeClass('dz-hidden-input');$(\"input[type='file']\").css({'visibility':'visible','z-index':'100','position':'relative','width':'300px','height':'20px'});";

    ((JavascriptExecutor) Browser.driver).executeScript(js, elem);
    elem.sendKeys(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the error?  We had a similar issue which was our tests ran locally on a Windows machine fine but when the tests were run via Jenkins on a Linux VM of course the path to the file changed to be relative to the Jenkins workspace.  Small tweak to look for the file relative to our workspace and all was well.

Comment: Hello Deon, the error is not because of the absolute file location/filename. The error is for the element not found. sendKeys is just sending a string to the textbox. I confirmed that the issue is because the javascript to make the element visible is not working. for the benefit of the doubt, this is the string that I sent: public static String uploadFilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\main\\resources\\File\\file.xls";

Comment: This is the error in the console: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
unknown error: path is not absolute: /home/ec2-user/test-build-develop-de/SourceCode/AutoTest/src/main/resources/File/file.xls

Comment: I added a log to print a text after sending the sendKeys but it did not display the log. it means the issue is the element not interacted.